# Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, laravel

### i have problem with register new user when i register new user this error shows up
"Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."
My .env file looks like :

```
 MAIL_MAILER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=mailhog
 MAIL_PORT=1025
 MAIL_USERNAME=xxx
 MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

---

my mail.php configuration  looks like:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Mailer
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
| messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
| and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
|
*/

'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mailer Configurations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
| their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
| you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
|
| Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
| sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
| mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
|            "postmark", "log", "array", "failover"
|
*/

     'mailers' => [
     'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailhog'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 1025),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
     ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
     ],

     'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'transport' => 'postmark',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'),
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],

    'failover' => [
        'transport' => 'failover',
        'mailers' => [
            'smtp',
            'log',
            ],
            ],
            ],

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Global "From" Address
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
            | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
            | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
            |
             */

              'from' => [
               'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
                 'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
                ],

                /*
                |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
               | Markdown Mail Settings
                |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
               |
               | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
              | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
            | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
                  |
                  */

            'markdown' => [
           'theme' => 'default',

                   'paths' => [
                   resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
                    ],
                ],

                   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing variable you need to add the mail from:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@domain.com
```

Comment: MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=a@gmail.com it is there in the file